# Ruby custom create method

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I scaffolded an Authorization(user_id, code, otherparam1, ...) and I want to add a custom_create method to the authorizations_controller which only require a code, the method generating the other parameters. I need this method to work with json or be called in others methods like User.newcustom(code)

```
def newcustom
  case request.method
  when :post #post
    code = params[:code]
    if(code and code != '')
      ...
      respond_to do |format|
      if @authorization.save
        format.html { redirect_to @authorizations, notice: 'Authorization was successfully created.' }
        format.json { render json: @authorizations, status: :created, location: @authorization }
      else
        format.html { render action: "new" }
        format.json { render json: @authorization.errors, status: :unprocessable_entity }
      end
    end
  else #get
    respond_to do |format|
      format.html
    end
  end
```

Here's my newcustom.html.erb

```
<%= form_tag( newcustom_authorizations_path, :method => :post ) do %>
  <div class="field">
    <%= text_field_tag :code %>
  </div>
  <div class="actions">
    <%= submit_tag('Get tokens') %>
  </div>
<% end %>
```

But it doesn't work through json, the form. And calling the method newcustom(:code => code) throws me a too many arguments (1 for 0). Any idea ?

Comment: Where do you call newcustom?

Comment: It's not php, dude! You need RESTful actions.

Comment: Show us the error message/stack trace and the code referenced in the error message.

Comment: @Tim : in an over method of my controller. But it works is drop the respond to format block for a redirect URL and change def new custom to def newcustom(code)

Answer (score 0):

for this add the given code to config/routes.rb

```
  resources :authorizations do
    collection do 
      post :newcustom
    end
  end
```

Answer (score 0):

Thanks for the help everyone.

I ended up solving my problem filtering the parameters of the create function, then calling my customcreate one.
AND YES I CHEAT :)